# Why key error is combining while combining List of dictionary with same keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary

```
dictio =[{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]
```

My desired out

```
{key1:[value1, value2, value3], key2:[value4, value5]}
```

My code throwing key error

```
{ k:[d[k] for d in dictio ] for k in dictio[0] }
```

i got solution from stack

```
d = {
    k: [d.get(k) for d in dictio ]
    for k in set().union(*dictio )
}
```

In this case out is having none

```
{'k2': [None, None, None, 'v4', 'v5'], 'k1': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', None, None]}
```

Comment: Because `d.get(k)` returns `None` if that key is not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over the dictionaries with `for d in dict`, and each time you use `d.get(k)`. If a dictionary does not contain that key, it returns `None`, hence these are the `None`s in the list.

I suggest you use a `defaultdict` instead, like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for subd in mydicts:
    for k, v in subd.items():
        result[k].append(v)
```

If you want to get rid of the "default" behavior after constructing the dictionary, you can wrap the result in a new dictionary, like:

```
result = dict(result)
```

so for the given sample dictionary, this will yield:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value4', 'value5']})
>>> dict(result)
{'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value4', 'value5']}
```

The above will work if dictionaries have multiple keys, etc. Furthermore we only make *one* pass over the list of dictionaries.

> **Note**: please do *not* name your variables after builtin functions/classes like `dict`, since now you overwrite the reference to the `dict` class.

Comment: This will produce different answer, as `defaultdict` will always produce value, while OP wants to add only values present.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, i misunderstood your answer, so disregard my comment, please.

Comment: from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)   TypeError: first argument must be callable or None

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{ k:[d[k] for d in dicts if k in d] for k in set().union(*dicts) }
```

Your code throws, because some dicts don't have all keys (for example `key1` in fourth dictionary). `if k in d` amends that alloing to continue only those, that have.

EDIT: you need to union your dicts as well, otherwise you won't get all keys, only those present in first dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee the specified order of list items, you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
{k[0]: [d[k[0]] for d in g] for k, g in groupby(d, lambda x: tuple(x))}
```

**Example**:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = [{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]

print({k[0]: [d[k[0]] for d in g] for k, g in groupby(d, lambda x: tuple(x))})
# {'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value4', 'value5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code from your original post need slight modification to get it working as intended

```
dictio =[{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value3'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]
d = {
    k: [d.get(k) for d in dictio if d.get(k) is not None]
    for k in set().union(*dictio )
}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value4', 'value5']}
```

Note usage of `is not None` for checking, which according to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

Different way to print

```
super_dict = {}
for d in dictio:
    for l, m in d.items():  
        super_dict.setdefault(l, []).append(m)
super_dict

{'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'key2': ['value4', 'value5']}
```

with collection set

```
import collections
super_dict1 = collections.defaultdict(set)
for d in dictio:
    for k, v in d.items(): 
        super_dict1[k].add(v)
dict(super_dict1)
{'key1': {'value1', 'value2', 'value3'}, 'key2': {'value4', 'value5'}}
```

list comprehension

```
combined_key_set= {key for d in dictio for key in d}
su_di = {key : [d[key] for d in dictio if key in d] for key in combined_key_set}
su_di
{'key2': ['value4', 'value5'], 'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
```

comprehension

`{key : [d[key] for d in dictio if key in d] for key in  [key for d in dictio for key in d]}`